# columns from django.db.models.query.QuerySet

Tags: django

With a raw query the columns for the SQL that will be executed can be accessed like this.

```py
    query_set = Model.objects.raw('select * from table')
    query_set.columns
```

There is no columns attribute for `django.db.models.query.QuerySet`.

I'm not using raw ... I was debugging a normal query set using Q filters ... it was returning way too many records ... so I wrote code to see what the results would be with normal SQL. I'd like the see the columns and the actual SQL being called on a query set so I can diagnose what the issue is without guessing.

How do you get the columns or the SQL that will be executed from a `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` instance?

Comment: First off, why not use the ORM to utilise `values` for columns you want? If you avoid `raw` you also get the safety & security of the ORM. If you really need to use `raw`, these docs should help with columns; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Comment: I'm not using raw ... I was debugging a normal query set using Q filters ... it was returning way too many records ... so I wrote code to see what the results would be with normal SQL. I'd like the see the columns and the actual SQL being called on a query set so I can diagnose what the issue is without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your comment, if you want to see what django has created in terms of SQL there's an attribute you can use on the `Queryset`.

Once you've written your query, `qs = MyModel.objects.all()`, you can then inspect that by doing `qs.query`, which if you print that out will show you the SQL query itself.

You'll have to inspect this query to see what columns are being included.

The `query` object is a class called `Query` which I can't find mention of in the django docs, but it's source is here; https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L136